# Custom view does not inflate from XML when referenced in Fragment.xml Android Application Development

Tags: java, android, sdk, layout-inflater

I have created a custom view in Android lets call it MyCustomView and its XML file is MyCustomView.xml. I referance MyCustomView in a fragment lets call it MyFragment and MyFragment.xml. The reference is only an XML reference not code. When my fragment inflates, it inflates utilizing the MyFragment.xml. I can then retrieve a pointer to the view. Here is my problem. Everything works as expected except MyCustomView did not inflate from MyCustomView.xml thus, none of the buttons or layouts defined in MyCustomView.xml are seen on screen. What might I be doing wrong? How can I make my XML reference in MyFragment.xml inflate with MyCustomView.xml?

MyFragment.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.domain.MyFragment"
    android:id="@+id/MyFragment">

    <com.domain.MyCustomView
        android:id="@+id/MyCustomView"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    </com.domain.MyCustomView>

</FrameLayout>
```

MyCustomView.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Next"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

MyFragment.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signature_capture, container, false);

        myCustomView = (MyCustomView) v.findViewById(R.id.signatureView);

        //At this point I would like to be able to 
        //access my buttons declared in MyCustomView.xml 
        //via the following call
       Button b1 = (Button) myCustomView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

       //The above line returns null because it cant find the view. 



        return v ;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know if this is problem but don't use *fill_parent* in custom view, reason: fill_parent is deprecated i.e. http://randomlytyping.com/blog/2014/2/9/matchparent-vs-fillparent

Comment: Secondly you are using android:layout_weight (custom view) but you have not set height nor width to **0px**

Comment: Thank you for your help. Its not a problem. The code Compiles and runs. Also I have some drawing logic in the MyCustomView.java that does draw to the screen as expected.

Comment: @MAGx2 thanks for your input a bit new to android development and still learning the ropes.

Comment: @MAGx2 thank you for the heads up on the deprecation. I had fill_parent all over in XML.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can only use a custom view in xml if you have defined a source (java) file for it which is a child of the `View` class or any of its descendants. Since you have only defined a custom layout, with no constructor, it cannot be inflated like a `View` can be. You should change:

```
<com.domain.MyCustomView
    android:id="@+id/MyCustomView"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
</com.domain.MyCustomView>
```

with:

```
<include
    layout=@layout/MyCustomView
    android:id="@+id/MyCustomView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</include>
```

and then move this attribute to your `MyCustomView.xml` root `FrameLayout`

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Im sorry steve  for not being clear I do have a source java file which inherits from View which is MyCustomView.java.  It was created via the Android Studio wizard. May I also add it is invoke and its constructor is called simply has no connection with MyCustomView.xml. It performs like a regular object without bindings to MyCustomView.xml.

Comment: @xMythicx if you are still interested in finding a solution please post your custom view java file and I will take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you steve although I believe I may have resolved my issue . It seems in Android development View is not able to contain any subviews/child views. Meaning if one would like to customize a view with other widgets buttons etc, the best approach would be to subclass one of the types of layouts ( Linear, Relative, Absolute). The term View in Android is completely different than iOS in what it represents.

Comment: I have view inflation like   <include
            layout="math.anubvam.com.coordinatorcalendar.TrackingView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"/>, but not working